# Hibernate Projection using case clause

Tags: java, case, hibernate-criteria

I have an Entity Class named `Student`.

```
@Table(name="t_student")
class Student{
    private String name;

    @Column(name="f_name")
    private String fatherName;

    private Integer age;

    // Accessor and Mutators methods ....
}
```

This is my`SQL` to get a particular result. And this works fine.

```
select s.name, s.f_name, case when s.age > 23 and s.age <=30
then 'Eligible' else 'Not Eligible' end is_eligible from t_student s;
```

In the above example I have pulled 3 (one based on `case`). I want to migrate raw SQL to hibernate `Criteria` query like below ....

```
session.createCriteria(Student.class)
    .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                           .add(Projections.property("name"))
                           .add(Projections.property("f_name"))
                           .add(/**Is there any options to use 'case' here for 'age'?*/)
    )
    .list();
```

How can I use `CASE` in `Projections` ?

Comment: what exactly is your question?

Comment: Can I use 'sql case' in Projections ? like `select s.name, s.age case when s.dob between '01/01/2016' and '31/12/2016'
then 'Eligible' else 'Not Eligible' end elig_alias from student_table s;`

Comment: @M. A. Khomeni: I've added your comment in your question. Feel free to click on the "Edit" link (just below your question) to add what happened when you tryed it...

Comment: @Louys Patrice Bessette: I have edited properly now, I think.